# Will my relay operate with a 12V battery and simple switch?

Tags: relay, 12v

If I have the following components:

1. 12v Car Battery
2. 12v 2amp relay
3. push button switch (normally open)

Can I simply just link all three components in series and expect the following:

1. The relay to fire
2. The relay to live

Or do I have to add additional components (resistors etc)?

The relay in question is this one: http://www.maplin.co.uk/2a-miniature-dpdt-latchingrelay-37529

Comment: and the answer appears to be yes I can :)

Comment: 15 minutes after your post. My guess, you managed to wait a full 5 minutes before deciding curiosity was more dangerous then fire. I applaud your self control :) Could you give a circuit of what you wired up? This answer is a bit sparse.

Comment: LOL at "*curiosity was more dangerous than fire*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work - obviously you connect to the "coil" pins. Note that that is a 2-coil latching relay: activating one coil will switch the contacts one way, activating the other will switch it back.

[Datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/105983/ETC/RSBL-12-S.html) (found by inspecting the part number with zoom on that page)

Answer (score 0):

That's how many safety and control switches work. You fire a relay with a little current and low voltage then the relay activates something bigger.